# Is there a way to create a picture of a sequence of screens in Latex (e.g. the procedure of a priming experiment)?

Tags: graphics, screen, sequence, schemata

I'd like to ask if you are aware of a method to create a picture of a sequence of screens in Latex. I want to include a picture/schema of the procedure of a priming experiment in my thesis, but I don't know where to begin. Do you know if anyone has already tried something similar? I attach here an example of what I'd like to realize [image: priming paradigm].

Thank you very much!!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE :) // So you ask for an animated film, or displaying some video-sequence in the compiled .pdf ?

Comment: Is your image format specific to your request, or merely illustrative of something more general?

Comment: Thank you @MS-SPO! I don't want to create videos, I'd like to create just an image similar to the one I posted. It is a schema describing a sequence of screens that I used in a behavioral experiment

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes the image I posted is very very similar to what I need ( I will only have to change words, but the sequence of screens is the same)

Comment: Sure, you can create such a diagram with package tikz,see https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf . It's a bit overwhelming at first, but also possible to master :) // If you can or want to use drawings, try free Inkscape, save as .eps and load it into your document. // Depends on your personal preferences.

Comment: Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here, I define a background wall on which to build.  I build individual "screens" with `\newscreen`, and then I use `\stackinset` to build the composite.  Finally, I place the `\stackinset` as a `tikz` node, so that I can lay a blue arrow nearby.

EDITED to use `standalone`, so that this compilation can be inserted in other documents as an `\includegraphics`.

```
\documentclass[border=0pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{stackengine,xcolor,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\newcommand\myscreen{\fcolorbox{white}{black}{\rule{50pt}{40pt}}}
\renewcommand\useanchorwidth{T}
\newcommand\newscreen[3]{%
  \savestack#1{\stackunder{%
    \stackinset{c}{}{c}{}{\textcolor{white}{\bfseries#2}}{\myscreen}%
  }{\tiny#3}}}
\tikzset{line/.style={draw, thick, -latex'}}
\fboxsep=0pt 
\sffamily
\savestack\Wall{\textcolor{white}{\rule{220pt}{180pt}}}
\newscreen\Fa{+}{750 ms}
\newscreen\Fb{}{200 ms\hspace{7em}}
\newscreen\Fc{apple}{50 ms}
\newscreen\Fd{dog}{}
\newscreen\Fe{}{50 ms}
\newscreen\Ff{cat}{Tail response}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep=0pt]
\node at (0,0) {\stackinset{l}{165pt}{t}{112pt}{\Ff}{%
\stackinset{l}{125pt}{t}{82pt}{\Fe}{%
\stackinset{l}{110pt}{t}{40pt}{\Fd}{%
\stackinset{l}{70pt}{t}{67pt}{\Fc}{%
\stackinset{l}{52pt}{t}{25pt}{\Fb}{%
\stackinset{l}{15pt}{t}{5pt}{\Fa}{\Wall}}}}}}};
\draw[line, blue]  (-3.6,.5)  to [|-] (1.7,-3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow thank you so much @Steven B. Segletes !! You've been super kind, I hope it didn't take too much of your time. Thank you again, this is exactly what I needed :))

Comment: You are welcome, @chiaras15.   You should have enough to work with here to adapt (colors, sizes, content, etc) to your situation.  Best wishes.

Comment: Thank you again very very much!!